# How to increase the value of a variable in a fields in Java?

Tags: java, object, methods, parameters, field

Im doing an homework question: "Write a method called addInterest() that takes a Loan object and increases the balance by adding interest at the specified rate."

My fields are:

```
public class Loan
{
    double interestRate;
    double balance;
}
```

My method's code is:

```
Loan addInterest(Loan getLoan)
    {
        Loan loan1 = new Loan();
        loan1.balance = getLoan.balance;
        loan1.interestRate = getLoan.interestRate;
        return loan1;
    }
```

How do I increase the balance by adding the interest? I've tried doing" return loan1.balance+loan1.interest;" but it wont work.

Comment: You have an interest rate so you have to calculate the interest.  Don't forget that maths still works in programs too ;)

Comment: You should look up what "Getters" and "Setters" do.

Comment: You have to start reading the book the teachers told you to read, not only do the exercises and hope that you will magically understand.

Comment: @fonZ Material we get taught is really brief... We don't get taught how to interpret this kind of calculation into objects and fields...

Comment: the parameters of the assignment aren't real clear, but from the code example it appears that a `Loan` may be intended to be immutable (but is not in the code example): in that case, perform the math on temporary variables and use those results to create a new `Loan` object which is returned.

Answer (score 0):

add inside your addinterest method and change return type to void

```
 this.balance = loan1.balance + loan1.interest;
```

ok then keep your return type and add this,

```
 loan1.balance = this.balance;
 return loan1;
```

but gota be honest with you, I don't really get the math here...

and if you want to retrieve the balance after you invoke the method, do this

```
 Loan debtor1 = addInterest(myLoan);
 System.out.print(debtor1.balance);
```

Comment: I have to use "Loan" as the object